# Facebook Album sorting

Tags: photos, facebook

I'm uploading dropbox photos to facebook via IFTTT but the problem is the photos are not sorted. Normally I have filenames as date-taken so it should be sorted bu I think IFTTT ignores that. And I couldn't find any options in Facebook Albums to sort by date taken or file name and managing them by drag-drop is impossible for me.

Is there any third-party app which can do this? There is a tool for flickr which can do this : http://sortmyphotostream.michael.tyson.id.au/

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I doubt this is possible, at least via Facebook API.